# no error but nothing executes after try catch statement

Tags: android

I'm trying to display data using a web service. The code gives no error but on button click the execution takes place only up to try part and nothing beyond that is executes

```
try {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You r in try", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);                
                // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
               //from here nothing executes but gives no error
                ****if(result != null**)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You r in if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      //Get the first property and change the label text
                      tv1.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());     
                }
                else
                {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
          } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }                         
        }
    });
```

Comment: HAve you tried to toast the result???What are u getting

Comment: clean your project and try again. also not use toast. use Log.i("TAG","Your message");

Comment: why not debugging the app and put a breakpoint on the problematic area ?

Answer (score 0):

Several methods you are calling throw exceptions.

"Jumping" over the code is an indication that an exception was thrown.

Put a toast in the catch block to confirm.

Comment: androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope); this line of the above code is not being executed rest all i checked by placing toast.

Comment: I had a more specific question: if you put a toast in the catch block, do you see that toast? If you do, then an exception in being thrown.